# Unable to filter records with LIKE operator

Tags: apex, trigger, soql

I am trying to filter accounts with customer record type and whose subject doesn't contains Training

So i wrote below query.

```
Id TrainingrecordTypeId = [Select Id from RecordType Where DeveloperName = 'Customer_Training'].Id;
String Keyword='Training'+'%';
if(CaseAccountIds <> null && !CaseAccountIds.isEmpty())
        {
            for(Account TT:[Select id,name,(Select id,Subject,recordTypeId from cases where 
                            recordTypeId =:TrainingrecordTypeId AND(Not subject Like:Keyword))from account 
                            where id in:CaseAccountIds])
            {
                cs.RecordTypeId=TrainingrecordTypeId;
                cs.Case_Assigned_Staff__c='Aidan Ross';
                cs.Subject='Training'+' '+'-'+' '+TT.name;
                cs.AccountId=TT.Id;
                TrainingCases.add(cs);
            }
        }
```

But i am not able to achieve it's creating cases even accounts having already cases with subject Training.where i went wrong

I am unable to save with below code and i am unable to attach account Id:

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your query [of type `Left Outer Join`] returns All Accounts as per Set/List: `CaseAccountIds` along with inner list of cases:

```
SELECT Id, Name, 
    (SELECT Id, Subject, RecordTypeId FROM Cases WHERE 
    recordTypeId =:TrainingrecordTypeId AND (Not subject Like:Keyword)) FROM Account 
    WHERE Id IN :CaseAccountIds
```

You need something like `Left Inner Join` which filters Account based on Cases.

Here is an example You might need to modify the query a bit:

```
SELECT Id, Name FROM Account 
    WHERE Id IN :CaseAccountIds AND
    Id IN (SELECT AccountId FROM Case WHERE 
        RecordType.DeveloperName = 'Customer_Training' AND
        (NOT subject LIKE :Keyword))
```

Note: You can get rid of one query if you directly filter with `RecordType.DeveloperName = 'Customer_Training'`.

I find this documentation quite helpful: [`A Deeper look at SOQL and Relationship Queries on Force.com`](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/A_Deeper_look_at_SOQL_and_Relationship_Queries_on_Force.com)

---

Solution added by OP:

> Not Operator is not working as expected in my case & my final query
>   looks like:
>
> ```
> SELECT Id, Name FROM Account WHERE Id IN :CaseAccountIds AND Id NOT IN 
>          (SELECT AccountId FROM Case WHERE RecordType.DeveloperName 
>           ='Customer_Training' AND (subject LIKE :Keyword))
> ```